# cannot upgrade Chromeos on HP Chromebox CB1-020. Stuck on ver76

Tags: javascript, replaceall, google-chrome-os

My sportsclub have several av these Chromebox'es but they will not run some javascript on some important webpages.  It sort of looks these Chromeboxes will not upgrade any more.

I check status on its "*About Chrome OS*" and it says "*Chromebox unit updated. Version 76.0.3809.136*". Also, "*Firmware = Google_Zako.5219.30.0*".

Latest is 119 today. That is why simple things, like `"mystring".replaceAll(...);` is not working on this box.

Is there a way, or how can I upgrade this box to newer ChromeOS versions?